# Find the remainder when $78$ is divided by $11$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Q)
Find the remainder when 7
8
 is divided by 11.

ANS

Here we define a%b is the remainder when we divide a by b.

```
We know that (ab) % c =[ (a % c)  (b % c)] % c

For example, (85) % 3 = [(8%3) (5%3)] % 3 = [22]%3 = 4 %3 = 1
```

72% 11 =49 % 11 = 5

74% 11 = [(72% 11) (72% 11)] % 11 = [55]%11= 25 % 11 = 3

78% 11 = [(74% 11) (74% 11)] % 11 = [33]%11 = 9

Hence the remainder when 78 is divided by 11 is 9.

AM i right?

Comment: "Discrete Mathematics Question" is second only to "Mathematics Question" in vagueness. You should try and make your title more specific.

Comment: @Dunka I don't know--"Question" might top them all. ;)

Comment: The need for rules like those shown in the grey box underline the problems that result when programmers/engineers are only taught about remainders as opposed to the conceptually more flexible and intuitive congruences. This is not meant to critique Mohd. It is just the way it is. One of my pet peeves that surfaced. Again.

Comment: Mohd. You are supposed to imagine a multiplication sign between $a$ and $b$ in that formula. On the other hand $78$ is a 2-digit number - not the product $7\cdot8$. The formula should read
$$(a\cdot b)\%c=[(a\%c)\cdot(b\%c)]\%c.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I suspect from the examples in the post that the rule (ab) % c =[ (a % c)  (b % c)] % c implies no multiplication sign, saying that, for example, 48 % 3 = 12 % 3 since 4%3 = 1 and 8%3 = 2. Of course this only applies when c is a single digit number (and not always), which explains why the OP is stucked when c = 11.

Comment: @Jyrki It is clearly a critique of mod, not Mohd, nor $(\rm mod\ )$. Gauss would approve.

Answer (score 5):

A very simple calculation will show that you are not correct:
$$
\color{green}{78}=\underbrace{\color{red}{77}}_{7\cdot 11=77}+\underbrace{\color{blue}{1}}_{\text{remainder}}
$$
Thus, you can see that when $78$ is divided by $11$ you actually get a quotient of $7$ and a remainder of $1$.

Comment: I tried adding colors to make it look fancy--did it work (felt kind of bad for answering otherwise)?